# displaying addition contents in div on select change using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm populating a dropdown based on ajax results returned as JSON, it works fine except that I want to display a div with description based on which option is selected.

here is the JSON

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "plan_name": "Plan 1",
    "description": "subscription something blabla.",
    "price": "500"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "plan_name": "Plan 2",
    "description": "another description",
    "price": "1000"
}
]
```

and here is my JS so far

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#plan").one("click", function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ROOT + "retrieve_plan",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(id, value) {
                    var opt = $('<option />');
                    opt.val(value.id);
                    opt.text(value.plan_name);
                    $('#plan').append(opt);
                });
                $('#plan').on('change', function() {
                    $('#description').show();
                    $('#description').html(value.description);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why did someone downvote without any comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` in the context of the `change` handler is `undefined`. You can use jQuery `data` method for storing the descriptions:

```
$.each(data, function(id, value) {
    var opt = $('<option />');
    opt.val(value.id);
    opt.text(value.plan_name);
    opt.data('description', value.description);
    $('#plan').append(opt);
});
$('#plan').on('change', function() {
     var desc = $('option:selected', this).data('description');
     $('#description').show().html(desc);
});
```